# AngularJS Service Availability

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am slightly confused by the Angular Docs...
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

**Questions:**

1. When I create a service in Angular, the service is instantiated when it's injected into a controller, correct?
2. Once a service is instantiated and I load data into the variables in the service, can I access the data the service is holding from another controller? Or does each controller create a new instance of the service?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services in Angular are singletons so one instance of a service is created the first time it is injected and everywhere the service is injected will share the same instance. So yes you can share information between controllers in a service.

Comment: Thanks @rob . This is the answer I need.